# Solving a first order nonlinear ODE (nonseparable)

Tags: differential

$$
f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{1-af(t)}dt
$$
How would one go about solving this equation? Does this equation have an analytical solution?
I have only learned different methods for solving linear ODE and PDEs, so I'm stumped by this equation. 
All I was able to do was get it into this form:
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{1-af(x)}, f(0) = c
$$
$$
f'(x)-af'(x)f(x)=1
$$
Which did not help me at all in finding a solution. As far as I can tell, this equation is not separable.
Suggestion will be great on methods for solving such equations.

Comment: The equation is separable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set $y=f(x)$, then we have
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{1-a y}$$
or
$$(1-a y)dy=dx$$
You can then solve $x$ as a function of $y$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** It looks like the left side of your last equation can be written as
$$\left(f(x) - \frac{a}{2}f(x)^2\right)'
$$